# Panoramio API get high resolution photos?

Tags: google-maps, google-api, panoramio

The API call, 
http://www.panoramio.com/map/get_panoramas.php?order=popularity&set=public&from=0&to=10&minx=-124.29382324218749&miny=36.089060460282006&maxx=-119.8773193359375&maxy=38.724090458956965&callback=MyCallback

Returns JSON like this, (coordinates are different from call here)

```
{"height":324,
    "latitude":42.758387999999997,
    "longitude":74.600364999999996,
    "owner_id":142670,
    "owner_name":"lazy_vlad",
    "owner_url":"http://www .panoramio .com/user/142670",
    "photo_file_url":"http:// mw2.google .com/mw-panoramio/photos/medium/29861949.jpg",
    "photo_id":29861949,
    "photo_title":"Warm summer evening...",
    "photo_url":"http:// www.panoramio .com/photo/29861949",
    "upload_date":"13 December 2009",
    "width":500}
```

The photo ID is , 29861949

The returned image is of medium resolution,
How can i make a call to return high resolution images?

The images used on the site is of this url, where photo IDs change
http://static.panoramio.com/photos/large/29861949.jpg

Can I use the static.panaramio in my apps or just the images returned by api call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

there is a size attribute on api calls, default is medium.

added `&size=original` with the api call.